# How can i filter by file word format on the dialog window when i upload an file .doc in Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, file, format, odoo-16

1

I have a model with an word file attribute:

```py
 word_file = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', 'document_ref_table_1', 'document_id_1', 'ir_attachment_id_1' , string="File Word", required=True)
```

Inside the view a show it with:

```py
 <field name="word_file" widget="many2many_binary"/>
```

This open an operating system dialog window that allows me to select an file. The problem is that I need to take only *.doc files and I don't know how to open this dialog windows filtered with this kind of file

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```xml
 <field name="word_file" widget="many2many_binary" options="{'accepted_file_extensions': 'application/msword'}"/>
```

or

```xml
 <field name="word_file" widget="many2many_binary" options="{'accepted_file_extensions': '.doc, .docx'}"/>
```

Comment: I want to ask more, when the win window opens it will default to .pdf or .doc as I want, but if I choose to change to another format, is there any way to just default to .doc and not select the option? other than you @aekis.dev

Comment: There is no way to do that in HTML so neither in Odoo. Also a huge recommendation it's to not relay in the file filter options and validate the file type based on the content in the server

Comment: Could you mark then my answer as accepted?